# How to fetch RSA authentication manager version?

Tags: authentication, version, access-control, identity-management

With every new version of `RSA` authentication manager, there are some changes in stub classes.

We are trying to load the jar of these `STUB` classes according to the version of `RSA` authentication manager.
So, is there anyway so that we can fetch `RSA` authentication manager version using some JAVA utility?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try Adding some code,

Comment: I don't have any idea from where to read the version.

Comment: This question is quite narrow to a specific commercial product that doesn't have very wide use. You'll probably get better results by asking the vendor of the product, or looking on their support forum. You are of course welcome to wait for an answer here, you never know if an expert will wander by.